# BeagleBone Black Network Connection issue

Tags: networking, debian, putty, beaglebone

I have been using a beaglebone black(bbb) for some time and for some reason, depending on what im doing my putty connection with the bbb will shutdown and i will receive the error: "Software caused connection abort". Recently, this keeps happening every time i try to build my kernel with the command:

```
./build_kernel.sh
```

After i use this command and the building processes reaches 57% i receive the connection abort error and this would happen repeatedly.I tried to use `dmesg` to see if i could spot any alerts the kernel may have made but nothing shows. Usually when i try to start my putty connection with the bbb it would take a few attempts before i would actually connect because i would get an error saying "Network error: Connection timed out" but when it finally connects its usually fine.

I also tried to place my laptop and bbb next to the router when building the kernel but i would still receive the connection abort error at 57%

My kernel version is: 4.19.94-ti-r42 and i am running debian 10

Does anyone know i can solve my networking issue? Thank you

Comment: does the board reboot at that point? check with `uptime`. Are you connecting via USB or Ethernet?

Comment: @TBR so after resetting my router the download reaches 98%, then fails with the error message"fatal: index-pack failed" and starts over from the beginning  and repeats until i receive a "Software caused connection abort" error

Comment: all that aside, I really don't recommend to build a kernel on the BBB. That's something that should be cross-compiled.

Comment: @TBR Do you know of any sources that can help get started with cross compiling a kernel? I guess i would have to do it on a computer running linux?

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-LinuxKernel